# Why wont this css code center the two elements on the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to centre the content on my page. I have a button and a paragraph of text on my page.

I'm new to css so I don't know what I should try.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  top: 921px;
  left: 400px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ff9b52 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

p.text {
  top: 2639px;
  left: 1014px;
  width: 398px;
  height: 88px;
  text-align: left;
  font: Regular 20px/27px Segoe UI;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #39316c;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>

<p class="text">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis
  necessitatibus sed officiis repellat illo ratione libero recusandae
  tempora dolorum excepturi. Velit odio mollitia nam vel, nulla nostrum
  officiis exercitationem esse!
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ff9b52 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis necessitatibus sed officiis repellat illo ratione libero recusandae tempora dolorum excepturi. Velit odio mollitia nam vel, nulla nostrum officiis exercitationem esse!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `flexbox` for that:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
button {
  top: 921px;
  left: 400px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ff9b52 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

p.text {
  top: 2639px;
  left: 1014px;
  width: 398px;
  height: 88px;
  text-align: left;
  font: Regular 20px/27px Segoe UI;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #39316c;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Click Me</button>

  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis
    necessitatibus sed officiis repellat illo ratione libero recusandae
    tempora dolorum excepturi. Velit odio mollitia nam vel, nulla nostrum
    officiis exercitationem esse!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox`. Take a look at this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Here is the solution for your current problem.

```css
html,body, .wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ff9b52 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

p.text {
  width: 398px;
  height: 88px;
  text-align: left;
  font: Regular 20px/27px Segoe UI;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #39316c;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Click Me</button>

  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis necessitatibus sed officiis repellat illo ratione libero recusandae tempora dolorum excepturi. Velit odio mollitia nam vel, nulla nostrum officiis exercitationem esse!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox technique as they say in other comments or you can add some lines to you code.

Add to `body` `text-align: center;` and add to `p.text` `margin: 0 auto;`

Your CSS code will become like that:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  top: 921px;
  left: 400px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ff9b52 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

p.text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 2639px;
  left: 1014px;
  width: 398px;
  height: 88px;
  text-align: left;
  font: Regular 20px/27px Segoe UI;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #39316c;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

See demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x6ave8br/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add
`text-align: center;`
and remember to remove the
`text-align: left;`
from your p.text

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider;

1. You are using `top` and `left` rules without giving a `position` rule value other than `static` (the default value). In your case you should use `position: absolute`
2. Don't use positioning with absolute values, if you don't need to. Absolute values (`px` unit) are not flexible enough to adjust to window size. Use relative units like `%` or `vw`/`vh`
3. For your contents to act as a group of elements, you should wrap it with a container element, which you then position accordingly (I used `<div class="center"></div>`)
4. I positioned this center container element absolutely using `top: 50vh` and `left: 50vw`. `100vh` is 100 per cent of the *view height*, i.e. the inner window height and `100vw` is 100 per cent of the view width likewise
5. This positioning is not enough, because it will position the top left corner of the `.center` element at the center of the window. We need to have a correction. I use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`. This will shift an element 50% of its width to the left and 50% of its height to the top, making it perfectly centered.

There are alternatives like `flexbox` mentioned in the other posts, but this one is a little bit more straightforward for a beginner like you. Nonetheless it is recommended to learn flexbox. You might want to read [A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on css-tricks.com

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

button {
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ff9b52 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

p.text {
  width: 398px;
  height: 88px;
  text-align: left;
  font: Regular 20px/27px Segoe UI;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #39316c;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <button>Click Me</button>

  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis necessitatibus sed officiis repellat illo ratione libero recusandae tempora dolorum excepturi. Velit odio mollitia nam vel, nulla nostrum officiis exercitationem esse!
  </p>
</div>
```